# jquery validate plug and ignore (JavaScript and jquery newbie)

Tags: jquery, validation

Is there a way to get the `var ignoreClasses` into `.validate()`?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var ignoreClasses="";

//this hides or shows the specific sections base ond the relationship select
$("#relationship").change(function() {
    switch ($(this).val()){

        case 'prospective-customer':
            $(".interest_all").hide();
            $("#interest_1").show();
            ignoreClasses = '.s2,.s4,.s5';
        break;
        case 'current-cutomer':
            $(".interest_all").hide();
            $("#interest_2").show();
            ignoreClasses = '.s1,.s4,.s5';
        break;
        case 'prospective-partner': 
            $(".interest_all").hide();              
            $("#interest_3").show();
        break;
        case 'applicant':
            $(".interest_all").hide();          
            $("#interest_4").show();
            ignoreClasses = '.s1,.s2,.s5';
        break;  
        case 'vendor':          
            $(".interest_all").hide();          
            $("#interest_5").show();
            ignoreClasses = '.s1,.s2,.s4';
        break;  
                                        
        default:
            $(".interest_all").hide();
        }   
});

// field validation
$("#leadform").validate({

     //I need to get the ignore class in here
    //like ignore: '.s2,.s4,.s5'


});
```

});

Additionally, the entire form validation only works if the user changes the `#Relationship` select box.  If a user just completes a their name, then clicks submit the form is not validated at all.

Comment: What do you mean by **get the var into .validate()**?

Answer (score 0):

`$("#leadform").validate({ ignore: ignoreClasses});`

You're passing in an object to the [validate method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options), so you have to use JSON syntax.

Also, I suggest you cache your jQuery selectors for better performance (not that it'd matter much in this case, but it's a good practice).

http://jsfiddle.net/jondum/Tua6c/

Answer (score 0):

if you want `.validation()` to run with the `ignoreClasses` you've specified within your `change` event listener, you have to call the `.validation()` method from within the event listener.  As it is, `ignoreClasses` will not be defined when `.validate()` runs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var ignoreClasses = "";

    var $interests_all = $(".interest_all");

    //this hides or shows the specific sections base ond the relationship select
    $("#relationship").change(function() {
        switch (this.value) {

        case 'prospective-customer':
            $interests_all.hide();
            $("#interest_1").show();
            ignoreClasses = '.s2,.s4,.s5';
            break;
        case 'current-cutomer':
            $interests_all.hide();
            $("#interest_2").show();
            ignoreClasses = '.s1,.s4,.s5';
            break;
        case 'prospective-partner':
            $interests_all.hide();
            $("#interest_3").show();
            break;
        case 'applicant':
            $interests_all.hide();
            $("#interest_4").show();
            ignoreClasses = '.s1,.s2,.s5';
            break;
        case 'vendor':
            $interests_all.hide();
            $("#interest_5").show();
            ignoreClasses = '.s1,.s2,.s4';
            break;

        default:
            $interests_all.hide();
        }
        // field validation (now being called from within the change listener)
        $("#leadform").validate({
            ignore: ignoreClasses
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much that works to for getting the values into the ignore. But there is a problem. The entire form validation only works if the user changes the #Relationship select box. If a user just completes a their name, then clicks submit the form is not validated at all.

Comment: Then what you need to do is declare `ignoreClasses` _outside_ of `$(document).ready()` so that it becomes a global variable.  Then attach your `validate` function to form submit by using a submit listener: `$('form#leadform').submit(function(){$(this).validate({ignore: ignoreClasses});});`

Comment: You could also leave `ignoreClasses` where it is and declare it like `window['ignoreClasses']=""`.  You would then refer to it the same way in your submit handler.

Comment: Thanks so much Jonathan, but I'm way over my head here so I don't know if I can make your solution work. I'll post my latest code above.

Comment: Don't get discouraged! You're almost there.